# Setting up Wamp Server that support Python

Tags: python, wamp, wampserver

I am trying to set up a WAMP server that will run Python scripts. I am an issue where the WAMP server icon will turn yellow, but says it's online. However, the server isn't accessible. I have tried switching ports and it doesn't fix the issue. When I edit the httpd.conf file and take out the line "LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so" and remove the wsgi module from the modules folder in the Apache folder, the server is accessible. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post my answer as this seems to be a common issue. using the wrong mod_wsgi version for Apache, I need it for Apache version 2.4, not 2.2.

Where precompiled binaries for Apache 2.4 can be found at:

- http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mod_wsgi

Ensure that the correct variant for combination of Apache version, Python version and 32 vs 64 bit is used.